# Import data to smith chart?

Tags: pgfplots

I have data in CSV format (or I can make it tab-delimited ASCII) and I would like to import it to a smith chart using the [`pgf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (edit: pgfplots) package. The data contains 2 columns with the real and imaginary impedance values, only the numbers. It's fairly easy to create scatter plots using x and y data from a CSV file using `\addplot[] table[x=X, y=Y, col sep=comma] {filename.csv}`. Is there a similar method for a smith chart?

example: I have the following data in a file called data.csv
RealZ   ImagZ
0.282   -0.196
0.366   -0.443
0.613   -0.205
0.654   -0.443

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[scale=1]
        \addplot[mark=*, only marks] coordinates {(0.282, -0.196)  (0.366, -0.443) (0.613, -0.205) (0.654, -0.443)};
    \end{smithchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I import the data without entering the coordinates manually?

Comment: Yes. `pgfplots` supports Smith charts. See its manual. Notice that `\addplot` is a command from `pgfplots` and not PGF or TikZ.

Comment: Yes, I know how to create smith charts with manually entered coordinate data but I'm not sure how to import the data from a file. I've looked in the pgfplots manual but they only example I see uses unit circle Cartesian coordinate data from a .dat file.

Comment: You can just try with the table command

Comment: Hmm interesting, that's the first thing I tried and it didn't work so I thought it required a different input format, but now its working. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.